# как распарсить числа из строки массива строк

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

я пока написал вопрос сам запутался

```
    import Foundation

var z = ["10 10 10 10", "20 25 20 25", "100 30 20 40", "23 40 44 100"]


for x in z {
    var s: [String] = []
    NSString(string: x).componentsSeparatedByString(" ") // [

}
```

дан массив z в котором в строках записаны размер стороны фигуры
нужно узнать какая это фигура

как я понял нужно просто распарсить строку массива -> потом сделать их intами -> сравнить и получить результат
так вопрос то в чем 
строку из массива я разделил получил четыре строки с цифрами как мне что то с ними сделать дальше с этими числами

Comment: если все 4 равны это либо квадрат либо ромб либо паралелограм, если 1=3 и 2=4 то это либо прямоугольник либо паралелограм, все остальное трапеция. что то типа такого. вы ничего в условии не пропустили?

Comment: забыл уточнить если 4 равны квадрат если 1=3 и 2=4 прямоугольник остальное трапеции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var z = ["10 10 10 10", "20 25 20 25", "100 30 20 40", "23 40 44 100"]


    for x in z {
        var values:[Int] = []
        let strValues:[String] = x.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for i in strValues {
            values.append(Int(i)!)
        }

        if(values[0] == values[1] && values[1] == values[2] && values[2] == values[3]) {
            print("квадрат")
        } else if(values[0] == values[2] && values[1] == values[3]) {
            print("прямоугольник")
        } else {
            print("трапеция")
        }
    }
```